# Managing user access for multiple git repositories on Linux server, granting access per repos based on SSH key?

Tags: git, ssh, repository, ssh-keys, user-accounts

I have a Linux server with some bare git repositories, that are being used remotely by several developers. Currently, all developers have access to all repositories.

I am using just one 'git' user account on the server, and each individual developer has their own SSH key through which they can access git through SSH.

Now, I intend to add a few more developers, but they should only have access to **some** of the git repositories, not all.

Is it possible to do this, while still keeping the single actual Linux user account (i.e. my 'git' user), and distinguish between the developers' SSH keys for managing access to the various repositories?

I've read some approaches using `gitolite`, not sure if that is still up to date of valid. What I liked about my approach so far is it doesn't require any additional setup or software, it's just basic git and SSH. Is that still possible if I want to assign different access rights per SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard OpenSSH server and want to give the restricted users multiple repositories, then no, you can't do this.  You can use OpenSSH's `authorized_keys` file to restrict a particular key to a specific command, but only one such command, so you can't distinguish across multiple repositories.

If you want to use a shared system user and multiple repositories with different user access rights, then Gitolite is a good choice.  It is still in use in lots of places and is not too difficult to set up.  You can additionally set up HTTP access with it as well (with a suitable HTTP server), should that be a thing you want to do.